# Maximum size of characters that can be sent through TCP socket

Tags: java, c++, string, max-size

I have a c++ client that sends a large string (Minimum size 10 KB) to a Java server application after a certain interval. During that interval the c++ application accumulates huge bytes of data and sends it completely to server.The server also receives it at one shot.

I want to keep the size of the string variable less than string::max_size at all times. Once the string's size approaches the limit I will  then send that string  to server and clear the string and only then move on collecting the remaining data.

and if the string can hold the complete data , will the entire data be transferred from client to server without fail.(Assuming no connection reset or any other such problem arises.)

Can somebody tell me If this is the way to proceed?

Comment: In general, yes. However, `string::max_size` is so huge that you will likely run out of memory long before reaching that string-size. But if you set some other, more reasonable, limit - then ok.

Comment: If you're on windows, the size of the UDP/TCP buffer is set by TcpWindowSize in the registry.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938219.aspx

Comment: @cup The *default* size. You can set it per socket with `setsockopt()`. No need to fiddle around with the Registry.

Comment: @EJP yes but if the size set by setsockopt is greater than what is in the registry, it doesn't work on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the client wouldn't know how big is the string, and it wouldn't know when to stop listening and start processing the received string.

You need to send the size of the string as an int, then send the data over. 
When the server has received all the data, it will know that the string has been received correctly.

Comment: It is a pity that SCTP is only widely used in some parts of the Internet (for example, in mobile networks). SCTP combines TCP-style reliability with UDP-style message boundaries (sending entire messages instead of a stream of bytes).

Comment: interesting I didn't know about it.

Comment: All true but you haven't actually answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I suggest you send the data as you acquire it, rather than adding latency and wasting space buffering it all up. TCP will take care of it.

Comment: thanks  for all your reply , ah @EJP I have to send the data only when the wait period elapses as per specifications , so I can accumulate the data upto a specified size which will be much less than string::maxsize   as "Bo Persson" correctly pointed out , that maxsize is such a huge figure the process might run out of memory.

Comment: @dau_sama this seems to be a correct way to check in the server end if all the bytes were recieved properly. Thanks for the suggestion.